# How to know connected slaves to a master in redis?

Tags: redis

In redis-cli in master system, what command is used to know the list of slaves connected to the master.

I only got command to know the status of a server.

To know the status of current server, open redis-cli:

```
> role
```

> 1) "master"
>
> 2) (integer) 196364
>
> 3) 1)
>
> ```
>   1) "192.168.1.90"
>
>   2) "6379"
>
>   3) "196364"
> ```
>
> 2)
>
> ```
>  1) "192.168.1.7"
>
>  2) "6379"
>
>  3) "196364"
> ```

Comment: I don't have a master/slave setup to test on, but maybe this is enough `redis-cli info | grep -A100 Replication`

Comment: @MarkSetchell No need for the grep IMO - just do `redis-cli info replication`.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Cool, thank you! We live and learn! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to list all replicas connected to a Redis master is by with the [`CLIENT LIST`](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) command, i.e.:

```
CLIENT LIST TYPE replica
```

Note: the `TYPE` subscommand was added in v5.